# Jetpack Compose syncronize Animated Visibility animation based on state

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation, jetpack-compose-animation

I am using an Material 2 version of a [BottomSheet](https://m3.material.io/components/bottom-sheets/overview) and I get the animations current progress, I want to synchronize the appearance of the Top App Bar so that when the Bottom Sheet is fully up it is also visible.

This question applies to other kind of animations as well, I've been reading documentation and I didn't find any way of controlling any animation based on state.

I've used different kind of animations but the nearest I've got is to animate the content's height based on that state, but this doesn't come from the bottom up.

Thanks!

Comment: [Transition](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#updateTransition) manages one or more animations as its children and runs them simultaneously between multiple states